# Grouping by date and count

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a summary that `groups by` `service name`, `count` and `date`. I am having trouble creating the desired result.

Two tables are joined; message and rest_message

```
SELECT distinct REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*'), count(*), 
trunc(m.CREATED_TS)
FROM MESSAGE m
INNER JOIN REST_MESSAGE k
ON m.id = k.id
WHERE m.CREATED_TS > sysdate - 30
GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*'), trunc(m.CREATED_TS)
```

The result looks like this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*') | COUNT(*) | trunc(m.CREATED_TS)
name1 | 1 | 2018-08-07
name2 | 2 | 2018-08-07
name1 | 3 | 2018-08-06
name2 | 4 | 2018-08-06
name1 | 5 | 2018-08-05
```

I would like this result instead:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*') | 2018-08-07 | 2018-08-06 | 2018-08-05
name1 | 1 | 3 | 5 
name2 | 2 | 4 | null
```

Comment: Look at the PIVOT option on SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case pivot method -

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*')
      ,CASE WHEN trunc(m.CREATED_TS) = '2018-08-07' THEN CREATED_TS ELSE NULL END AS '2018-08-07'
      ,CASE WHEN trunc(m.CREATED_TS) = '2018-08-06' THEN CREATED_TS ELSE NULL END AS '2018-08-06'
      ,CASE WHEN trunc(m.CREATED_TS) = '2018-08-05' THEN CREATED_TS ELSE NULL END AS '2018-08-05'
FROM MESSAGE m
INNER JOIN REST_MESSAGE k
ON m.id = k.id
WHERE m.CREATED_TS > sysdate - 30
GROUP BY REGEXP_REPLACE(k.rest_Action, '\d+', '*')
```